# stdin:1: '=' expected near '<'

Tags: lua

So I'm starting to Learn Lua, my problem is that in a tutorial that teaches you to create Guess My Number Game starts with this line:

```
name = "John"
print<name>
```

So in the tutorial shows that prints the name but in mine gives this error:

```
stdin:1: '=' expected near '<'
```

Please, what am I getting this?

Thank you for all your help.

Comment: I'm fairly sure that's supposed to be `print(name)`.

Comment: Wow, worked. yeah <> and () in cmd or Lua IDE looks the same. Such a simple thing, Well thank you, I appreciate!

Comment: You may want to upvote and/or mark Adam's reply as answering your question, since he wrote an actual answer pointing out the same thing :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Functions use parentheses to enclose their arguments, so the second line should be

```
print (name)
```

Comment: It also may be worth noting you can drop the parenthesis if the only argument is a string/table.